# Mongodb filter embeded docs by parent field

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have the following structure in my mongodb:

```json
{
    "preferred_child": "child_id_2",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "child_id_1"
        },
        {
            "id": "child_id_2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the mongo shell, how can I select the parent data and only the preferred child (the child which has the "id" equal to the parent's "preferred_child" id)?

Answer (score 1):

try to use [.aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with filter like this:

```
db.parent.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project:
                {
                preferred_child : 1,
                children:{
                    $filter:{
                        input:"$children",
                        as:"item",
                        cond:{
                            $eq:["$preferred_child","$$item.id"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```